# Blurry Text with C# Listview when reducing flicker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a System.Windows.Forms.ListView containing numerous items. 
It was flickering intolerably (as seems to often be the case) so after some searching I decided to do these 2 things in a "ListViewLessFlicker" class.

```
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
```

DoubleBuffering didn't have much effect even though it's most commonly given as the solution in these topics, but setting the style opaque to true hugely reduced flickering.
http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=273

However it had a side-effect that I can't seem to find a fix for.
When I hover my mouse over an item in the ListView it now makes the text bold and **very** blurry (this doesn't happen unless opaque is true).

Here is a very zoomed in example.

[image]

If anybody has a fix or knows why it may be doing this I'd love to know!

Comment: When does the flickering happen? When items are added?

Comment: One suggestion - not an answer - update your graphics drivers.

Comment: flickering happens on refreshing the listview which must be done frequently i.e on the listview1.endUpdate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually do this - reduces flickering when resizing the control. You need to use [`BeginUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) / [`EndUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to reduce flickering when adding items in bulk. I don't know what may cause the blurring, so I can't advise about that - updatig your video driver may help but don't hold your hopes high.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory ( "" )]
public partial class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    private const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x14;

    public ListViewEx ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        // Turn on double buffering.
        SetStyle ( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true );

        // Enable the OnNotifyMessage to filter out Windows messages.
        SetStyle ( ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true );
    }

    protected override void OnNotifyMessage ( Message oMsg )
    {
        // Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message to prevent the control
        // from erasing the background (and thus avoid flickering.)
        if ( oMsg.Msg != WM_ERASEBKGND )
            base.OnNotifyMessage ( oMsg );
    }
}
```

Comment: that is essentially my class too except mine has opaque and strangely I found one with if(oMsg.Msg != 0x14) etc... and not decimal 14.

Comment: @user1001328 Hmm, let me double-check the `WM_ERASEBKGND` value - this is real code copy & pasted in here, so I'm fairly sure this should work. Let me double-check.

Comment: @user1001328 You were right, it's `0x14` - I fixed the answer. Strange because I'm sure I used this code to eliminate flickering. Do note, that flickering is caused by the control erasing its background and then repainting its white background over the default gray. If you don't filter out `WM_ERASEBKGND`, setting other controls styles have effectively no effect.

Comment: Strange indeed, most people say this helps but it's not reducing my flicker, noticeably at least... Yeah that's why opaque is meant to be useful, as it is supposed to make it not require that repaint.

Comment: @user1001328 is it flickering when you're adding/removing items or does it happen when you resize the window or uncover parts of your list by moving a window on top of it?

Comment: It's flickering on every endUpdate() which is being called very frequently to keep the data fresh.

Comment: @user1001328 Is your `ListView` sitting directly on your form or is there a container control that hosts it? I had massive problems with flickering when I had my lists on tab controls.

Comment: It's in a split container, which is on the form.

Comment: @user1001328 The split container is your problem - likely both for flickering and for the blurry effect. I tried using it, too and eventually gave up. I couldn't figure out any way to make it work correctly. Give it a try, put a `ListView` on a resizable form with the above code, I'm pretty sure you won't have flickering (or at least not nearly as much). This is why I switched to using tabs instead of the split container - the `TabControl` has `DoubleBuffered` property. I wonder if this also depends on the version of the .NET framework used...

Comment: argh, I thought that had fixed it but it still flickers :(

Comment: @user1001328 If you have a small repro project that you can upload somewhere, I'll try it on a different machine and see. I'm out of ideas why this fails but now you made me curious about the problem. :)

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this so late. I can't upload the project source or I would probably swiftly become very fired :). My boss ended up thinking the slowly darkening was tolerable so we went with that. I'll set this as the answer since it comes close and apparently works for some people.

Comment: @judgeja I understand the correlation between uploading stuff & getting fired. :)  Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you and I found solution in the comments on this page: 
http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=273

You have to create new class like this:

```
public class BufferedListView : ListView
{
    public BufferedListView() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }
}
```

and then define your ListView as BufferedListView like this:

```
ListView myListView = new BufferedListView();
```

After that blurry text is not a problem any more ;)